# mPDF Page break conditions

Tags: mpdf

Every document I generate has list (`<ol><li>`) with text and footer with captions.

Sometimes there are situations (when document content is huge) when second page contains only block with captions.

[image: now]

Is there any way to move 1-2 list items to the second page instead of moving only the captions:

[image: i want this]